# How to get the status of a webhook using the Docusign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I made a call to GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/connect/{connectId} to get some information about a DocuSign webhook, but it does not contain any information about its status (active, inactive...).

Is there any way to know its status or to activate the webhook through the API ?

Comment: ***Welcome! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status attribute is named **[allowEnvelopePublish](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/connect/connectconfigurations/get/#schema_200_connectconfigresults_connectconfigresults_configurations_allowenvelopepublish)**

`true` means the webhook is active